# Crystal Reports 'Advanced' Layout

Tags: layout, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I've been recreating some existing reports and I've come up against a layout I'm simply unable to reproduce - which is surprising, because it's quite straight forward at first glance.

It's basically 3 groups of data on a single page, presented as a standard table (details) and a chart, side-by-side, as below:

[image: Crystal Report Layout]

I've managed to achieve this for a single group of data (by inserting another Report Header, set to 'Underlay Following Sections' in Section Expert) but cannot get any further.

Any ideas how to achieve this in Crystal Reports XI?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you haven't already done so, insert a group
- insert a second section for the group; set it to `underlay following section`
- add a chart to the first group-header section (`gha`); position it to the right side of the page
- add/move column-header fields to the second group-header section (`ghb`); position to the left side of the page
- keep table's rows in the `details` section

You will probably need to adjust the height of the `gha` to meet your needs